# Azure synapse, how do I pass date parameter in SQL query?

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

While using Azure Synapse Pipeline, I made some parameters which are studentID,startDate, and endDate.
I wanted to pass the parameters to SQL query, so

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE date BETWEEN @{pipeline().parameters.startDate} AND @{pipeline().parameters.endDate}
AND student_id = @{pipeline().parameters.studentID}
```

I think the studentID parameter was read but date part doesn't seem to be read. So after I ran this query I got empty table with only columns.

However, If I manually give the date like,

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-02-01'
AND student_id = @{pipeline().parameters.studentID}
```

it works perfectly with the conditions.
but I need to pass the parameters instead of writing date in the query.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The static query and dynamic query with startDate and endDate don't match in your case. Look at the following demonstration.

- The following is sample data in my table:

[image]

- I have a demo table where I am querying based on the condition that `startDate` column lies between '2022-05-01' and '2022-06-01' and id>=1. When I give query same as yours, the run fails. You can see the debug input to check what query is being run.

```
select * from demo where startDate between @{pipeline().parameters.startDate} and @{pipeline().parameters.endDate} and id>=@{pipeline().parameters.id}
```

[image]

- You can see that it is not the same as the static query that runs successfully. The date values must be enclosed within quotes for it to be a valid query. So, enclose the parameters `startDate` and `endDate` within single quotes to get the desired output.

```
select * from demo where startDate between '@{pipeline().parameters.startDate}' and '@{pipeline().parameters.endDate}' and id>=@{pipeline().parameters.id}
```

[image]

You can always check the debug input for the activity where you are using your SQL query with dynamic content to check what query is getting executed.